# Encrypt data before sending to SQL by VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, encryption

I need to create an application where most of the data written to DB is encrypted. For that sake it shouldn't be visible/obtainable by any of the super users who can access that DB Server. Which is ok because the data is to be encrypted. The problem is that I should not have a way to see it or way to obtain it neither, however the manager user should be able to see it.

The application will be authenticating users using LDAP however I could grab the password when it's inputed to the form by the user and use that password as an encryption key so all data gets saved to DB encrypted and can be decrypted with that same password.

I have few concerns with this idea:

1. What if the user forgets password and gets a new one by doing password reset on LDAP?
2. How can I give access to this data to manager user?

I am thinking I could store the first password inputed by the user in DB encrypted with some built in function and use the encrypted string without decrypting. I could then give the manager users a way to decrypt this data using those keys but again that means I know how it works so I can take those keys from DB and decrypt if I wanted to.

What is the best approach here?

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem, your question is quite broad.  However, consider the following:

Each users data is encrypted with a different symmetric key.  Let's call this key `k1`.  So, for each user, there exists one and only one `k1` key that is associated with that user and that user alone.  `k1` is generated for each user when they create an account.

Each user also has a key, `k2`, that is derived from their password.  `k2` is not stored on the server, only derived from an inputted password from the user, when necessary.  We use `k2` to encrypt `k1` and store the result of this encryption in the database with the users other data.

This facilitates easy password changing:  Instead of having to decrypt and then re-encrypt all the users data every time the user wants to change their password, all we have to do is decrypt with the old `k2` to get `k1` and then re-encrypt with the new `k2` to get a new ciphertext for `k1`.  All the users data is still securely encrypted with `k1` but we need the new password to derive the new `k2`, which `k1` is now encrypted with.

You can follow a similar scheme for your "manager" account.  Every users `k1` key is encrypted with a key derived from your managers password and stored with the manager.  They can then use their password to decrypt any `k1` key.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing in my logic. I need to encrypt the encryption key with the password from the user. I know my question was broad but unfortunately I have no other way to get this type of information but you guys. I have searched for the answer as I always do before posting but non of the answers covered my logic the way I needed.